# C++ OpenGL wireframe cube rendering blank

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I'm just trying to draw a bunch of lines that make up a "cube". I can't for the life of me figure out why this is producing a black screen. The debugger does not break at any point.

I'm sure it's a problem with my pointers, as I'm only decent at them in regular c++ and in OpenGL it gets even worse.

```
const char* vertexSource = 
    "#version 150\n"
    "in vec3 position;"
    "void main() {"
    "   gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);"
    "}";

const char* fragmentSource = 
    "#version 150\n"
    "out vec4 outColor;"
    "void main() {"
    "   outColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);"
    "}";

int main() {

    initializeGLFW();

    // Initialize GLEW
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();

    // Create Vertex Array Object
    GLuint vao;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    // Create a Vertex Buffer Object and copy the vertex data to it
    GLuint vbo;
    glGenBuffers( 1, &vbo );

    float vertices[] = {
         1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, // Vertex 0 (X, Y, Z)
        -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, // Vertex 1 (X, Y, Z)
        -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, // Vertex 2 (X, Y, Z)
         1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, // Vertex 3 (X, Y, Z)
         1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f, // Vertex 4 (X, Y, Z)
        -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f, // Vertex 5 (X, Y, Z)
        -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, // Vertex 6 (X, Y, Z)
         1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f  // Vertex 7 (X, Y, Z)
    };

    GLuint indices[] = {
        0, 1,
        1, 2,
        2, 3,
        3, 0,
        4, 5,
        5, 6,
        6, 7,
        7, 4,
        0, 4,
        1, 5,
        2, 6,
        3, 7
    };

    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo );
    glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof( vertices ), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW );
    //glBindBuffer( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    //glBufferData( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof( indices ), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW );

    // Create and compile the vertex shader
    GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader( GL_VERTEX_SHADER );
    glShaderSource( vertexShader, 1, &vertexSource, NULL );
    glCompileShader( vertexShader );

    // Create and compile the fragment shader
    GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader( GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER );
    glShaderSource( fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentSource, NULL );
    glCompileShader( fragmentShader );

    // Link the vertex and fragment shader into a shader program
    GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader( shaderProgram, vertexShader );
    glAttachShader( shaderProgram, fragmentShader );
    glBindFragDataLocation( shaderProgram, 0, "outColor" );
    glLinkProgram (shaderProgram);
    glUseProgram( shaderProgram);

    // Specify the layout of the vertex data
    GLint posAttrib = glGetAttribLocation( shaderProgram, "position" );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray( posAttrib );
    glVertexAttribPointer( posAttrib, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0 );

    // Main loop
    while(glfwGetWindowParam(GLFW_OPENED)) {

        // Clear the screen to black
        glClearColor( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

        // Draw lines from 2 vertices
        glDrawElements(GL_LINES, sizeof(indices), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indices );

        // Swap buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers();
    }

    // Clean up
    glDeleteProgram( shaderProgram );
    glDeleteShader( fragmentShader );
    glDeleteShader( vertexShader );

    //glDeleteBuffers( 1, &ebo );
    glDeleteBuffers( 1, &vbo );

    glDeleteVertexArrays( 1, &vao );

    glfwTerminate();
    exit( EXIT_SUCCESS );
}
```

Comment: You need to start from a known good example and work up from there. Make incremental changes and test between each change.

Comment: Make sure you pass the right arguments to every function. For instance, your call to glDrawElements uses sizeof(indices) to specify the number of elements in the indices vector. This is wrong, since the sizeof() function returns the number of bytes, and an int uses 4 bytes. You can either declare indices to be of type GLubyte or divide the sizeof(indices) by sizeof(int).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no view or projection matrix, so your view volume is a cube 2 units wide and 2 units high and centred on the origin.

Coincidentally, you are drawing a cube that is 2 units wide and 2 units high and centred on the origin. So your cube is getting draw just on the outside edge the view volume.

Draw a smaller cube (use +/-0.5f for vertex coords) and you should see something.

That's assuming that the rest of the code is fine...